# GitHub Email Issues on commiting the code

Tags: git, github, devops

I have only email attached to the github account. While committing the code from eclipse ID, I noticed a different email ID.

Looking for better solutions, Thanks..!

Comment: `git config user.email` possibly?

Comment: And you probably would like to ```git commit --amend --author``` the revisions already created.

Answer (score 0):

Your Github account does not matter to the commits made in Git. The commits are made with your local Git configuration and are sent to Github unchanged; they must be, because commits in Git cannot be changed (Git history is not rewritten but replaced).

You need to configure your local Git with your desired email address. You can do this either by editing `~/.gitconfig` directly, or by running `git config --global user.email your@email.address`. See [Setting your email in Git](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/) for more detail.